# SRS: how different between Scenarios and Process narrative(UML)

Tags: uml, scenarios, srs

In Software Requirements Specification,

what is the difference between Scenarios and Process Narratives of each function (described using UML)?

I understand that Scenarios are descriptions of a single feature of the system.
Is it necessary to describe Scenarios also with UML, or are the text descriptions sufficient?
Because I already have to detail Process narrative of each function(feature) with UML.

Both approaches are equivalent, right?

thx, guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use both, you should use all teh techniques that are fit to communicate what are you modeling. There are things which are traditionally better expressed using text (use case descriptions, algorithms, ...) and there are those which are better described graphically (class hierarchy, relations, various flows...). So it is up to you to decide what notation is best for the thing you want to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use both UML and text, and for text you may include tables, paragraphs, non UML charts.

Both specification techniques are complementary, in case some feature is missing in one, the other may included.